# Add validation to tkinter code

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a GUI using tkinter.

On frame 2 of my code I have an entry widget.  I only want numbers to be valid.  How do I print an error message in the text widget if letters, special characters, symbols, spaces etc are input in the entry widget after pressing the button?  In python I've used While True but I don't know if this can be used in tkinter and if it is where I would place the validation in my code.

My code is below.

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3 
from tkinter import StringVar
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import ttk

df = {"Option B":[0,10,25,100,120,140,160,200,500,800,1200,1700,2000],
    "Option A":[0,0,15,90,110,130,150,190,490,790,1190,1690,1990]}
price_options = pd.DataFrame(df,index=["0",
                        "1 - 50",
                        "51 to 75",
                        "76 to 90",
                        "91 to 100",
                        "101 to 110",
                        "111 to 130",
                        "131 to 150",
                        "151 to 170",
                        "171 to 190",
                        "191 to 225",
                        "226 to 255",
                        "Over 255"])


class My_GUI(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

    # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
    # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
    # will be raised above the others
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (StartPage, Page2, Page3):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame

        # put all of the pages in the same location;
        # the one on the top of the stacking order
        # will be the one that is visible.
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame("StartPage")

def show_frame(self, page_name):
    #Show a frame for the given page name
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome.....\nCheck how much it will cost......\n", font=controller.title_font)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Item A",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Page2"))
    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Item B",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Page3"))
    button1.pack()
    button2.pack()

class Page2(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Select from the options below", font=controller.title_font)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

    global df
    tk.Label(self, text='Select option:').pack()
    self.options = ttk.Combobox(self, values=list(price_options.columns))
    self.options.pack()




    label = tk.Label(self, text="How much does the item weigh?", font=controller.title_font)
    label.pack()

    self.weight_entry = tk.Entry(self)
    self.weight_entry.pack()

    tk.Button(self, text='Click here to display price', command=self.show_option).pack()

    self.text = tk.Text(self)
    self.text.pack()

    tk.Button(self, text="Restart",
              command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage")).pack()

def show_option(self):
    identifier = self.options.get() # get option
    weight_id = int(self.weight_entry.get())
    self.text.delete(1.0, tk.END)   # empty widget to print new text
    #self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options[identifier]))


    if identifier == "Option B":

        if weight_id == 0: self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[:1,1:2]))
        elif weight_id >= 1 and weight_id <= 50: self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[1:2,1:2]))
        elif weight_id >= 51 and weight_id <= 75 : self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[2:3,1:2]))

    elif identifier == "Option A":
        if weight_id == 0: self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[:1,:1]))
        elif weight_id >= 1 and weight_id <= 50 : self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[1:2,:1]))
        elif weight_id >= 51 and weight_id <= 75 : self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[2:3,:1]))


class Page3(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Some text here...", font=controller.title_font)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
    button.pack()        

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = My_GUI()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, and you've posted way too much code that is completely unrelated to the question being asked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could wrap the input in a try/except, the function `int()` automatically strips outer spaces (an error will be thrown for a space between digits and any not digits characters)

```
    def show_option(self):
        identifier = self.options.get() # get option
        try:
            weight_id = int(self.weight_entry.get())
            self.text.delete(1.0, tk.END)   # empty widget to print new text
            if identifier == "Option B":

                if weight_id == 0: self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[:1,1:2]))
                elif weight_id >= 1 and weight_id <= 50: self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[1:2,1:2]))
                elif weight_id >= 51 and weight_id <= 75 : self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[2:3,1:2]))

            elif identifier == "Option A":
                if weight_id == 0: self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[:1,:1]))
                elif weight_id >= 1 and weight_id <= 50 : self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[1:2,:1]))
                elif weight_id >= 51 and weight_id <= 75 : self.text.insert(tk.END, str(price_options.iloc[2:3,:1]))            
        except:
            self.text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            self.text.insert(1.0, 'Wrong input')
```

Answer (score 2):

Entry widgets have validate options that allow only "valid" input to be added to the Entry. Meaning, if the user tries typing letters or any other non-numeric character into the Entry, they won't show up:

```
class Page2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...

        vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate), '%S')
        self.weight_entry = tk.Entry(self, validate='key', vcmd=vcmd)
        self.weight_entry.pack()

        ...

    def onValidate(self, S):
        if S in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
            return True
        else:
            # output warning message here
            return False

    def show_option(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Works perfectly. I will use this in my code.